# <a href=…> syntax error unexpect something

Tags: php, html

```
   <?  $i = 0;
            foreach( $model->authors as $key => $author){
            ?>
                <?
                //if (++$i < count($model->authors)) echo $author->name.';'; else echo $author->name.' ';
                if(++$i<count($model->authors)) 
                {
                    <a href="http://192.168.171.46:9090/search/index?keyword=<? echo $author->name; ?>"><? echo $author->name.';' ?></a>;
                }else echo 
                    <a href="http://192.168.171.46:9090/search/index?keyword=<? echo $author->name ?>"><? echo $author->name.' ' ?></a>; 



                 ?>
            <? }
        ?>
```

but it shows this line syntax error unexpect < after {  I can't find this error?

Comment: `<?php ?>` Never use the shorthand for starters, and your else is missing an opening bracket, and a ton of other syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$i=0;
foreach($model->authors as $key=>$author) { 
    if(++$i<count($model->authors)) {
        echo '<a href="http://192.168.171.46:9090/search/index?keyword='.$author->name.'">'.$author->name.';</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="http://192.168.171.46:9090/search/index?keyword='.$author->name.'">'.$author->name.' </a>';
    }
}
```

Or if you don't mind a slight change use this because it is a little simpler:

```
<?php
$ret='';
foreach($model->authors as $key=>$author) 
   $ret.=($ret?'; ':'').'<a href="http://192.168.171.46:9090/search/index?keyword='.$author->name.'">'.$author->name.'</a>';
echo $ret;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're coding PHP, do it like this:

```
<?php  
$i = 0;
foreach( $model->authors as $key => $author){
    if(++$i<count($model->authors)) {
        echo "<a href='http://192.168.171.46:9090/search/index?keyword=" . $author->name . "'>" . $author->name . "</a>";
    } else {
        echo "<a href='http://192.168.171.46:9090/search/index?keyword=" . $author->name . "'>" . $author->name . "</a>"; 
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach( $model->authors as $key => $author){
    if(++$i<count($model->authors)){
        ?>
        <a href="http://192.168.171.46:9090/search/index?keyword=<?php echo $author->name; ?>"><?php echo $author->name.' '; ?></a>;
        <?php
    }
    else{
        ?>
        <a href="http://192.168.171.46:9090/search/index?keyword=<?php echo $author->name; ?>"><?php echo $author->name.' '; ?></a>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

I see you're very confused with the syntax - perhaps you should consider using editor with syntax checking at least for the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($model->authors as $key => $author):
        if (++$i < count($model->authors)): ?>
            <a href="http://192.168.171.46:9090/search/index?keyword=<?= $author->name ?>"><?= $author->name ?>;</a>
        <? else: ?>
            <a href="http://192.168.171.46:9090/search/index?keyword=<?= $author->name ?>"><?= $author->name ?> </a>
        <? endif;
    endforeach;
?>
```

Or a shorter version.

```
<?
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($model->authors as $key => $author): ?>
            <a href="http://192.168.171.46:9090/search/index?keyword=<?= $author->name ?>"><?= $author->name,++$i < count($model->authors) ? ';' : ' ' ?></a>
        <?
    endforeach;
?>
```